# Select color from array while plotting a folium map

Tags: jupyter-notebook, folium

I'm trying to create a map displaying some restaurants in their locations in a Jupyter Notebook and folium. Also, the restaurants are assigned with different categories. I want to assign a different color for each category.

I add the code I have so far.

df_unicos is a pandas dataframe containing all the different categories of restaurants available (i.e 15, 0 to 14). If I comment (#) the lines containing the 'mo' variable it works but all the markers have the same color.

```
rangocolores=len(target['Venue Category'].unique())

# create map of the restaurants of Terrassa using latitude and longitude values
map_restaurants = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=14)

#set color scheme for the clusters
x = np.arange(rangocolores)
ys = [i + x + (i*x)**2 for i in range(rangocolores)]
colors_array = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ys)))
rainbow = [colors.rgb2hex(i) for i in colors_array]

# add markers to the map
markers_colors = []
mo=0
for lat, lng, venu, barri in zip(target['Venue Latitude'], target['Venue Longitude'], target['Venue Category'], target['Neighborhood']):
    mo=df_unicos[df_unicos['Restaurante'].str.contains(venu)].index.item()
    label = '{},{}'.format(venu, barri)
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html=True)
    folium.CircleMarker(
        [lat, lng],
        radius=5,
        popup=label,
        color=rainbow[mo],
        fill=True,
        fill_color=rainbow[mo],
        fill_opacity=0.7).add_to(map_restaurants)

map_restaurants
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

It points to the line:

```
mo=df_unicos[df_unicos['Restaurante'].str.contains(venu)].index.item()
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot!
Arturo

Answer (score 0):

I'm so new in python...

Changing

```
.str.contains()
```

to

```
.str.match()
```

solved the issue.